# GoogleApiClient called every time device screen is turned off and on again

Tags: android, google-api-client

Since I need the users location for my async task, I use the LocationServices api to get the users latitude and longitude. then in onConnected, I execute the async task. I do this in onConnected and not onCreate, as I need the users location.

The problem is that whenever I turn the screen off and on again, onConnected is called again, causing the async task to execute again.

Here are my methods for the GoogleApiClient.

```
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
    Log.e("Connected?", String.valueOf(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()));
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        super.onStart();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i("onConnected", "onConnected called"); //called everytime screen is turned off and on again
        new asynctask().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.i("ConnectionFailure", "onConnetion failed");
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: use a flag to execute the statement only once

Comment: Great idea. Solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a flag to execute the statement only once